# Oculus Quest Single-Pass and Multi-Pass not working?

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, lwrp, quest

I am using the following configuration:

Unity: 2019.2.13f1

Device: Oculus Quest Using LWRP

Issues:
(a) When I change the "Stereo Rendering Mode" to "Single-Pass", the rendering of the screen is too small and too far.

(b) When I change the "Stereo Rendering Mode" to "Multi-Pass", the rendering is only visible on the Left-Eye.

(c) The only Mode that works is "Multi-View". Unfortunately, there is also of jittery motion when this is used. The images that are near the user starts to jitter and this is very much visible.

The (c) is the reason that I would like to use Single/Multi pass rendering since then it would overcome the problem.

Has anyone faced these similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

This is a recurrent problem with LWRP/URP because it use post-processing effects, and single-pass stereo rendering needs you [to tweak shaders to support this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SinglePassStereoRendering.html)
And thus, unless vis major, it is best suited to stick with standard rendering pipeline.